# Android Studio 4.0. LayoutInspector: how to open a few tabs?

Tags: android

This week I updated Android Studio till 4.0 version. 
Its new LayoutInspector certainly has many useful features, it's great!
but in previous versions of Android Studio i had the opportunity to open a few tabs of different screens using layout inspector.

Does anybody know how to do it in Android Studio 4.0? 
Because now in version 4.0 LayoutIspector has another view in separate window and no any tabs.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Finally i've figured out my problem.

In fact Live Layout Inspector of version 4.0 provides complete information about app's UI structure and hierarchy for emulator/device with API level 29 or higher.

But if you need the previous version's view of Layout Inspector, then you just have to disable **Live Layout Inspector**:

File -> Settings -> Experimental, and check the box next to Disable Live Layout Inspector.